# Show total of values by month

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

[image]I have a simple table that shows invoices and the date they were created. I am looking for a way to show the total of the invoices values at the bottom of the last row of every month while showing the table.

Example:

| Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 04-05-2020 | $50 |
| 02-05-2020 | $30 |
| 14-05-2020 | $10 |
| **TOTAL** | **$90** |

| Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 04-07-2020 | $15 |
| 02-07-2020 | $15 |
| 14-07-2020 | $15 |
| **TOTAL** | **$45** |

Any idea? This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FACTURAS</title>

<style>
    
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "facturas";

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

die("CONNECTION ERROR " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM facturas_table ORDER BY id";
$facturas = $conn->query($sql);

echo '<table>

<thead>

    <tr>

        <td>ID</td>
        <td>DATE</td>
        <td>INVOICE</td>
        <td>PRICE</td>

    </tr>

</thead>';

while ($row = $facturas->fetch_assoc()) {

$month = substr($row['fecha'], 3);

// $totalMonths = "SELECT SUM(monto) as montoTotal FROM facturas_table WHERE fecha = ''"

echo '
<tbody>

    <tr>

        <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['fecha'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['factura'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['monto'].'</td>

    </tr>

</tbody>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it have to do with mysqli?

Comment: be sure to only post the relevant parts of the code - i.e. the html header and the style really does not matter

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with all that code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to divide html from php if anyhow possible, as the mix will create problems in the future. Also try to use english language for all variable names (I assume monto is the price).

What I got from your question is, that you try to create the table and also calculate the total. Therefor you would create a variable for the sum and add the current amount of each row to the sum variable (in each iteration of the loop).

I changed the relevant php part:

UPDATED to your comment (sorry this was not so clear from your question).

Important is the trick with `$lastMonth` and `$month`, as well as with `$first`

```
<tbody>
<?php
$total = 0; $lastMonth = ""; $first = true;
while ($row = $facturas->fetch_assoc()) : 
 $month = substr($row['fecha'], 3);
 $total += $row['monto']; ?>

<?php if(!$first && $lastMonth != $month): ?>
    <tr> 
        <th colspan="2">Total (<?=$month?>): </th>
        <th colspan="2"><?=$total?></th>
    </tr>
<?php $total=0; endif; ?>

    <tr>

        <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['fecha']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['factura']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['monto']?></td>

    </tr>



<?php $first=false; $lastMonth = $month; endwhile; ?>


    <tr> 
        <th colspan="2">Total (<?=$month?>): </th>
        <th colspan="2"><?=$total?></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>


</table>
```

didn't try out the code (so be sure to check for syntax), but you can get the idea how to do that pretty well

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is close to what I want. But what I am looking for is to show the total of price by months. Take a look at the example in the question, please.

Comment: Example: 3 prices in april, 2 prices in january and 5 prices in november. I want to show the total of every month at the bottom  the last row for that month.

Comment: See my update - maybe you clarify that in your question a bit more

Comment: This gave me an idea, but I don't know how to test this on my side since your php syntax is a little bit different and I am not sure if I am understanding it correctly.

Comment: Please, take a look at the image I updated in the question. That's what I get when trying your code on my side.

Comment: You are invited to work with my code - the idea is clear? My code was not tested, and I don't know if your variables hold the values one would expect. so be sure to be sure first (i.e. does your month extraction work? In which field is the price - I don't know any japanes, or what language you use ). and for the month total: you could put the total line first in the loop, that should fix the break between june i.e.

Comment: Your idea took me to a solution and now I have it working ok. Thank you so much. But should I accept your answer?

Comment: Sure, as the idea of SO is not to solve your problem but answer your qeustion and help you learn

Answer (score 0):

while @helle's answer focuses on a solution on PHP side, here's an answer on the database side:

```sql
create table `facturas_table`(`id` bigint primary key, `invoice` varchar(100), `price` bigint, `date` date);
insert into `facturas_table` (`id`, `invoice`, `price`, `date`) values
    (1, "A25C45", 5000, str_to_date("04-05-2020", "%d-%m-%Y")),
    (2, "A25C46", 3000, str_to_date("02-05-2020", "%d-%m-%Y")),
    (3, "A25C47", 1000, str_to_date("14-05-2020", "%d-%m-%Y")),
    (4, "A25C48", 1500, str_to_date("04-07-2020", "%d-%m-%Y")),
    (5, "A25C49", 1500, str_to_date("02-07-2020", "%d-%m-%Y")),
    (6, "A25C50", 1500, str_to_date("14-07-2020", "%d-%m-%Y"))
;

select * from (
   select `id`, `invoice`, `price`, date_format(`date`, "%d-%m-%Y") `date`, date_format(`date`, "%Y-%m-%d") `ordering_format` from `facturas_table`
union all
   select null `id`, null `invoice`, `price`, `month` `date`, date_format(str_to_date(concat("01-", `month`), "%d-%m-%Y"), "%Y-%m-32") `ordering_format` from (
      select sum(`price`) `price`, date_format(`date`, "%m-%Y") `month` from `facturas_table` group by `month`
   ) `totals`
) `a` order by `ordering_format` asc;
```

From there on

```php
<-- Some Code -->
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>DATE</th>
         <th>INVOICE</th>
         <th>PRICE</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
<?php while($row = $facturas->fetch_assoc()): ?>
   <?php if ($row["invoice"] === null): ?>
      <tr style="font-size: bolder">
         <td colspan="2">Total <?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
         <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row["price"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>DATE</th>
         <th>INVOICE</th>
         <th>PRICE</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php else: ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["invoice"]; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["price"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<-- Rest of Code -->
```

Note that since `date` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, it is wrapped in backticks (`). It is good practice to wrap any user-defined names (even if they are not reserved) in backticks to avoid confusion and unnecessary and hard-to-catch syntactic bugs.

Also Note that price is written in cents and its type is `bigint`. It's also good practice that:

1. Use `bigint` for integer primary keys on tables that are going to be massive in the long run and most probably getting archived in a warehouse in the future, too. That way you have plenty of time before rotating IDs, better still, use some long guaranteed unique values like `UUID`s and `GUID`s as primary key. In this case, if invoice numbers are going to be unique, it's best to be chosen as ID since it's the natural ID of this kind of records.
2. Use the smallest possible currency of the target market, this way you will avoid using decimals (which are inefficient) or worst floating point numbers (which are terrible at precision, since computers work in base 2 and humans work in base 10). Also, if you needed to divide any currency values (like calculating rebate and discounts), always use the same rounding policy on the smallest currency. For example, if you are going to give a 10% discount on an item with 9.95$, you can choose the policy to round discount up (to avoid customer dissatisfaction), but stick to it all the time, also use `BCD` operations since they are calculating values like humans do and not like computers do, but are expensive. Use them in sensitive error prone situations like this (not just adding simple integers, but divisions and multiplies)

```php
$price = 995;
$discount = 10;
$discounted_value = explode(".", bcdiv(bcmul($price, $discount, 2), "100", 2), 2);
$discounted_value = $discounted_value[0] + (($discounted_value[1] + 0) !== 0);
$final_price = $price - $discounted_value;
```

Finally, if you think you are going to deal prices greater than `PHP_INT_MAX` (take care that it's different in 32-bit and 64-bit versions), just go full berserk mode and use strings in combination of `bcmath` operations for prices.

Having a good online business!